# wget fail to save audio files in a page

Tags: audio, wget

I am running this wget, able to save everything (css, html, images, relative path reference etc)  from a webpage,  except the audio (alert.mp3, alert.ogg)

Is it due to limitation of wget when come to getting this audio from this format?

```
<?php
    exec("wget --no-parent --timestamping --convert-links --page-requisites -erobots=off http://webpage/index.html");
?>

<html>
<body>
bla bla bla

<audio autoplay="autoplay" preload=""><source src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="alert.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of wget are you using? Maybe it's too old to understand `audio` and `source`?

Comment: am using version 1.12

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.16, and all the audio works!